# ColdFusion ( CF ) - How to setup a Google Directory API Service Account using ColdFusion 11 (ColdBox 4.0)

Tags: coldfusion, service-accounts, coldbox

Cannot seem to get this working.

Here is the documentation for setting up the service using Java: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

I am attempting to recreate this in ColdFusion. This is my code:

```
    var p12File = createObject( 'java', 'java.io.File' ).init( [File Location] );
    var accountId = JavaCast( "string", "[Account Email]" );

    var GoogleCredential = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder" );
    var HttpTransport = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport" );
    var NetHttpTransport = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport" );
    var JsonFactory = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory" );
    var JacksonFactory = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory" );
    var Directory = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory$Builder" );
    var DirectoryScopes = createObject( "java", "com.google.api.services.admin.directory.DirectoryScopes" );
    var Collections = createObject( "java", "java.util.Collections" );


    var credential = GoogleCredential
        .setTransport( NetHttpTransport )
        .setJsonFactory( JacksonFactory )
        .setServiceAccountId( accountId )
        .setServiceAccountScopes( Collections.singleton( DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER ) )
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File( p12File )
        .build();

    var service = Directory.Init( NetHttpTransport, JacksonFactory, javaCast( "null", "" ) ).setHttpRequestInitializer( credential ).build();
```

Everything appears to work fine until I try to create the service. I get the following error message:

```
    Object instantiation exception. An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''.
```

I am using ColdFusing 11 ColdBox 4.0 if that makes a difference. Thanks in advance for any assistance you guys can lend!